# Email Configuration tab is missing in MSD CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

On MSD CRM 2013 (on-premises) I've recently upgraded to CRM 2013 Rollup SP1 and I check I'm not able to find new sections like Email Configuration,Post configuration, Post Rule Configurations sections from Settings.

Please suggest.
Thanks,
Kiran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to import Microsoft's 'Add Email and Post Configuration to SiteMap' managed solution

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn486920.aspx#BKMK_ImportSolution